# Adding GPG key inside docker container causes "no valid OpenPGP data found"

Tags: ubuntu, docker, openpgp

I'm trying to install New Relic's system monitoring inside a docker container, but the `apt-key add -` fails with `no valid OpenPGP data found`.

There is the full `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Matej Koubik

RUN echo deb http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/ newrelic non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list
RUN wget -O- https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install newrelic-sysmond
RUN nrsysmond-config --set license_key=...
RUN /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond start
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution provided by @xdays works around the problem, but also works around the protection that ssl is providing.  You could install the [`ca-certificates`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ca-certificates) package before issuing your wget statement and it should work with ssl.

Add the following line before your call to wget:

```
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates wget
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue when i was installing docker.

run 
`sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common`

You can refer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04).

And then 
`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

Answer (score 5):

it seems that the problem is wget, add `--no-check-certificate` to your wget, and everything is ok.

```
# wget --no-check-certificate -O- https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg | apt-key add -                                                                 
--2014-01-12 09:29:30--  https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg
Resolving download.newrelic.com (download.newrelic.com)... 50.31.164.159
Connecting to download.newrelic.com (download.newrelic.com)|50.31.164.159|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify download.newrelic.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1682 (1.6K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

100%[=================================================================================================================================================>] 1,682       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-01-12 09:29:31 (15.1 MB/s) - written to stdout [1682/1682]

OK
```

Comment: The accepted answer is the correct one (add the ca-certificates); turning off certificate check reduces safety, while there is a simple solution above.

Comment: I followed the correct one (adding the ca-certificates) but nope, still get the same error?  So I have to use this one and reduce the safety unfortunately.  No idea why it still fails even though the ca-certificates are installed before wget and the call to apt-key add.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `wget -O- https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg | apt-key add -` seperately with `wget -O- https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg` and `apt-key add -`. You can refer [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found/3857/3).

And this is same for `curl`.