# Best approach of using gpg key generation for docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gnupg, entropy

I have to generate a key with gpg in my Docker image with `gpg --gen-key`, but it takes too long for the key generation because of the entropy. On a local machine i can fill up my entropy with `rng-tools`, but how can i implement this in my `Dockerfile`?

During my research i found some solutions, but no one of them satisfied me really.

Can you share your approach of generating a key in a Dockerfile?

EDIT:

The purpose of the key generation in the Dockerfile is, that i have to download encrypted files (which is encrypted with the public key of the docker container) from a server, decrypt it and make it available on my docker container/server.

The articles, i found for this purpose:

[GPG Key Generation Fails on Alpine Linux Docker Image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277282/gpg-key-generation-fails-on-alpine-linux-docker-image)

[Decrypt with gpg from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519303/decrypt-with-gpg-from-inside-a-docker-container)

[Dockerize everything - run gpg inside container](https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerize-everything-run-gpg-inside-container/12313)

[Adding GPG key inside docker container causes “no valid OpenPGP data found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909111/adding-gpg-key-inside-docker-container-causes-no-valid-openpgp-data-found)

Comment: I guess you should describe what you try to achieve. Automatically generating keys during software builds is usually _not_ something desirable and usually there are better solutions. "During my research i found some solutions," -- in this case, _always list them_, or people will likely come up with exactly what you already tried and just waste their and your time.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have already encrypted files in some other place and want to use them inside the container? You won't succeed in doing so by generating a new, random key, you have to import the existing private key instead.

Comment: This was the next problem, what i didn't mentioned in the question... After every image build, the public key of the container is different and i have to exchange the public key of the container with opposite side... So you recommend to generate a key on my local host machine, export the private key of the generated key and add it to my docker image in the dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, or pass it in at runtime (for example using host volumes) if you do not want to include it in the image.

Comment: Okay, this was my assumption to do it this way.. But the idea of sharing volumes is a little bit better :). Can you descripe your points in an answer, that i can accept it and we close this?